# How would I perform many random operations to a set of images?

Tags: c#, php, image-manipulation, batch-processing, gimp

I need to manipulate an image such that a sub-rectangle of it is flipped or rotated relative to the rest of the image. Here's an example:

[image]

This manipulation needs to happen many times, each time producing a new modified image from the original (rather than applying successive modifications to one image).

The size of the sub-rectangle needs to vary systematically (perhaps in 5% increments from 10% to 75%) and the location of the sub-rectangle needs to vary randomly.

Lastly, this procedure needs to be carried out on a large number of images.

**How would I go about this?**

My options are PHP, C#, or batching in Gimp. That said, I'm prepared to learn something new if there's a particularly sensible approach.

Comment: Ask: How to flip and rotate a sub-rectangle in C#. Not: Guess my favourite programming language and send me the codes.

Comment: You could do this with imagemagick (no need to go as far as the gimp). Probably not the most efficient approach, however.

Comment: @dtb: you misspelled "codez".

Comment: @dtb Point taken, but choosing a technology first seemed backwards. I honestly have no preference about tools, so wanted to see suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id say go with C# and write yourself a little utility.

The [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac148eb3.aspx) class may have all of the methods that you need.

Id suggest that you look at the [`DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040.aspx) and the [`RotateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662.aspx) functions.

Answer (score 1):

Is this something that needs to be done programatically or is it a one-time deal?

If programatically, it *can* be done in PHP using the GD library, but its not going to be easy or fast, due to the fact that you'll have to write a routine to manually move pixels.

A summary of "easyness" of your request based on a PHP GD library approach:

- Manipulation happens many times, each time producing a new modified image from the original: **easy**
- Size of the sub-rectangle needs to vary systematically, **easy**
- Location of the sub-rectangle needs to very randomly, **easy**
- In-image rotation **moderate difficulty, and slow**
- Performing this on a large number of images, **easy**

I don't have enough experience in C# of Gimp to give you any definitive answers there; Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could take your favourite language, they will all 3 be capable, code it and run it?

Comment: The question isn't really specific so I'm not sure what he wants and give a direct answer?